# OS X server continuous integrations with cococapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, osx-server

I am using cocoapods in my project and want to integrate with OS X Server to use continuous integration (CI). I did not commit pods to git, and after CI server downloaded source code, it is unable to find .xcworkspace file. Is here some way to run "pod install' after downloading source code but before integration ?

Comment: We need more information to know about your CI server. Typically this is possible by running simple commands, but we have no idea what your current setup is.

Comment: server is OS X Server application on Mavericks, all settings by default.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding pods to git too. If you really want to install pods on server, you can write custom shell script which would clean pods and the reinstall them and add it as "Run script build phase" (Select project, select target, select Build Phases, then press Editor->Add Build Phase->Add Run Script Build Phase in top menu). Don't forget to update PATH value in this script before calling `pods`.

But for me adding pods to git was more convenient in other ways too.

Comment: I know about "run script build phase", but problem is CI cannot find .xcworkspace, and cannot run script.  Any way thanks for  
advice to add pods to git)

Comment: Did you add .xcworkspace to git? I mean, are you sure it is not ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to install cocoapods on your build machine. SSH into the machine and run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

AND THEN

```
pod setup
```

After cocoapods is installed. Go to XCode and make sure you have selected the correct branch under Source Control at the top of the screen.

Then setup the bot as usual and when you get to the Before and After options, include the following script:

[image: Before Integration Script]

Where repository_directory_name is the name of the folder containing your Podfile and .xcproject file. I actually have a rake file there that pulls down the submodules as well as running pod install.

If you are seeing build errors when the integration runs, specifically if it is complaining about finding the cocoapods repo, try including

```
pod setup
```

before cd repository_directory_name. Have the integration run one time and then remove the pod setup line (this is hacky but it just needs to be done one time to set up cocoapods for the _xcsbuilduser account.

I hope this helped!